# R language test normally distributed

Tags: r

i have this table

```
                     A                 B                 C
1     8.15277310472498  120.119697226183 -19.9730763584375
2     4.83146238750758  127.444687091065 -17.6775842159986
3    -36.2827393317865  141.404497199928  13.3305739285424
4    -17.7694197933543 -127.432770534059 -53.5002410318702
5     25.9688056175644 -72.9976248054808  32.9571663681418
6    -34.9730561135594  4.29842837742877  32.0193630829453
7    -26.9079081708146  57.0696019664296  11.9220941327512
```

and i want to check if each row is normally distributed

i tried

```
> shapiro.test(csv$A)
> shapiro.test(csv["A"])
> shapiro.test(csv[1])
```

i got an error for all the above commands

```
Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

Comment: Can you show us the results of `str(csv)` ?  Your latter two commands should have been `shapiro.test[["A"]]` and `shapiro.test(csv[[1]])`, but the first should have worked unless you somehow accidentally got non-numeric values in your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
shapiro.test(as.double(csv$A))
```

Answer (score 2):

You said by row, right? (Not tested) where df is your dataframe (I am not sure with three observations in each row, how could this test be possible to calculate?)

```
apply(df,1,shapiro.test)
```

Example using mtcars data from R:

```
> apply(mtcars,1,shapiro.test)
$`Mazda RX4`

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i] 
W = 0.6063, p-value = 3.047e-05


$`Mazda RX4 Wag`

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i] 
W = 0.6071, p-value = 3.119e-05
```

......(omitted).....